# Fasthosts shared platform PHP mail from web page issue -F

Tags: php, email, webmail

I am trying to send email from a web page hosted on a shared platform over at fasthosts. I cannot for the life of me get this to work, I had a much more extensive script which checked the validity of email etc, but now I've been reduced to using the basic example from fasthosts and it is still not working.

Please could someone take a look and let me now where I am going wrong...

```
<?php


    // You only need to modify the following two lines of code to customise your form to mail script.
    $email_to = "contact@mywebsite.co.uk";          // Specify the email address you want to send the mail to.
    $email_subject = "Feedback from website";   // Set the subject of your email.

    // This is the important ini_set command which sets the sendmail_from address, without this the email won't send.
    ini_set("contact@mywebsite", $email_from);

    // Get the details the user entered into the form
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    // Validate the email address entered by the user
    if(!filter_var($email_from, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Invalid email address
        die("The email address entered is invalid.");
    }

    // The code below creates the email headers, so the email appears to be from the email address filled out in the previous form.
    // NOTE: The \r\n is the code to use a new line.
    $headers  = "From: " . $email_from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email_from . "\r\n";    // (You can change the reply email address here if you want to.)

    // Now we can construct the email body which will contain the name and message entered by the user
    $message = "Name: ". $name  . "\r\nEmail: " . $email . "\r\nMessage: " . $message ;



    // Now we can send the mail we've constructed using the mail() function.
    // NOTE: You must use the "-f" parameter on Fasthosts' system, without this the email won't send.
    $sent = mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers, "-f" . $email_from);

    // If the mail() function above successfully sent the mail, $sent will be true.
    if($sent) {
         $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$name .' Thank you for contacting us.'));
        die($output);
    } else {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }

?>
```

Comment: `it is still not working` -- can you clarify? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No errors at all, just a constant processing animation.

Comment: Well, PHP is not producing an animation. That's likely to be your web page. Are you making the request to this PHP script via AJAX? If so you first need to use your browser's Developer Tools to check if anything went wrong with the JavaScript or the AJAX request. You can also use it to see what response you got the from the PHP script (if any) and what status code the response had.